# How to generate an image from dynamically created HTML in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am writing an nodejs script which will generate some info-graphic images using HTML.

I have used `jsdom` library to generate the graphics with basic html elements (divs, headings, paragraphs, etc.).

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { document } = (new jsdom.JSDOM()).window;

const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
wrapper.style.cssText = "background:#eee;";
...
const el = document.createElement("div");
el.style.cssText = "background:red;";
el.innerText = "Sample Text";
...
wrapper.appendChild(el);
```

I can save this generated html (`wrapper`) to a file. The saved file looks as expected. So the HTML generation part works fine.

But **my requirement is to generate an image file** (png, jpg, svg, or anything similar) with this generated html view.

I have tried, `dom-to-image` and `html-to-image` both failing saying "HTMLCanvasElement is not defined". I understand that since there is no browser in nodejs runtime, there are limitations such as these.

Is there a way to somehow generate an image from these generated HTML?

NOTE: This script will be running on a CICD pipeline on a linux server.

Comment: I'm late to the party but you could try puppeteer (headless chrome), I've never used it but seen good results in a specific app I collaborated in for a while. https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A little bit of a self-plug here but I just recently did the same thing with a project called [kb-hologram](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kibibit/kb-hologram).

It basically takes handlebar templates (either SVG or HTML), and renders that to either an SVG or png.

Basically, after having a ready HTML file, I load the HTML into a puppeteer instance (which actually runs a headless chrome browser), take a snapshot of the rendered HTML, and saves it.

it can generate things like [a test report image](https://github.com/Kibibit/kb-hologram/blob/next/src/__image_snapshots__/image-maker-spec-ts-image-maker-should-generate-a-coverage-image-from-template-1-snap.png) (obviously fake numbers), or [a changelog image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kibibit/kb-hologram/next/src/__image_snapshots__/image-maker-spec-ts-image-maker-should-generate-changelog-from-html-template-1-snap.png) similar to what vscode publishes in their tweets:
[image]

### HTML

Here's the gist of it:

```js
// handles rendering the HTML templates
// https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import { writeFile } from 'fs-extra';

(async () => {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({
    height: this.options.height,
    width: this.options.width
  });

  // If your HTML is saved to a file, you load it like this:
  await page.goto('file://' + this.templateFilePath);

  // if your HTML is in memory (as a string), you load it like this:
  // page.setContent(htmlString);

  const imageBuffer = await page.screenshot({});

  await browser.close();

  // write file to disk as buffer
  await writeFile('rendered.png', imageBuffer);

  // convert to base64 string if you want to:
  console.log(imageBuffer.toString('base64'));
})();
```

### SVG

Generating an SVG is much simpler since it's basically a text file:

```js
import { compile } from 'handlebars';

(async (data) => {
  // generate the svg template as string
  const template = await this.getTemplateAsString();

  // make it a handlebars template
  const handlebarsTemplate = compile(template);

  // load the data into the template
  // this is basically the content of the SVG file
  const svgString = handlebarsTemplate(data);

  // from here on, it's basically the same thing :-)
  const svgBuffer = Buffer.from(svgString, 'utf8');
})(data);
```

### Headless browser

To me, handling things like external resources is easier on a real browser if you want to load fonts and styles from CDNs.
There are solutions out there to take a screenshot from jsdom directly if you don't want to introduce another "browser" module into the mix.
Also, take note that this will download an instance of chrome as a dependency

---

### kb-hologram

The project is still in early stages. Feel free to contribute to [kb-hologram](https://github.com/Kibibit/kb-hologram), fork the code, or write your own using the example. **I personally use it on `Travis CI` to publish tweets and images as PR comments on GitHub.**

Comment: Excellent. Works perfectly. I just had all the content in memory. Need to do some minor tweaks to take the screenshot in the size I want. Thank you.

Comment: sure! my pleasure! you basically change the size of the image based on the size of the viewport. you can pass whatever `width` and `height` that suits your needs and that will be the dimensions of the screenshot

Comment: Quickly went through the puppeteer API and found that you can clip the screenshot. Updating the answer to include clipping.

Comment: Usually clipping the rendered HTML is done when you just want to render a small portion of it. Since you are the one that is writing your templates, it sounds like you don't really need clipping. No?

Comment: Yeah. You don't. But in my case, my element size is dynamic. I cannot define the browser size beforehand. So, I make the browser bit large and crop the screenshot to the size I need by using the element size.

Comment: Finally hit a wall since Puppeteer does not run on CentOS 6.x which my CICD pipeline runs on. I can't change the OS at the moment. So looking for alternatives. Open for suggestions. :/

Comment: @charith.arumapperuma maybe this will help:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/391#issuecomment-517489272